# How to have a tiled image for a portion of a window cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, background-image

I'm new to this and it's hard for me to even ask my question right because I don't know the right terminology. I've done some objective c coding so I'm a little bit beyond beginner except when it comes to working with UIs.

I would like to know the best practices to accomplish this - i.e. the right way.

I have a window with some buttons at the top of it. Below that is a region that will have an *image or webview*. This will be of variable size so to make it look nice I'd like to have the area behind it have a nice tiled pattern.

I've experimented with a few things that work but everything feels a bit hackish. Is there a control that automatically provides a tiled background and lets me put other controls inside of it? For that matter, is there any kind of control that allows putting other controls inside of it? (I'm used to this in GTK but it doesn't appear to be common in Cocoa)

Also, considering that the image can change sizes based on the buttons above, should I be using core animation and it's layers (I've read about them but not used them)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly simple way to do this is to use a custom NSView subclass for the background view. In its -drawRect: method, write code to take the image and draw it repeatedly to fill the bounds of the view. The algorithm to do this is pretty simple. Start at the top left (or any corner really), draw the image, then increment the x position by the width of the image, and draw again. When the x position exceeds the maximum x coordinate of the view, increment y by the height of the image and draw the next row, and so on until you've filled the whole thing. This should do the trick:

```
@interface TiledBackgroundView : NSView
@end

@implementation TiledBackgroundView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    NSImage *image = ...
    NSSize imageSize = [image size];

    //  start at max Y (top) so that resizing the window looks to be anchored at the top left 
    for ( float y = NSHeight(bounds) - imageSize.height; y >= -imageSize.height; y -= imageSize.height ) {
        for ( float x = NSMinX(bounds); x < NSWidth(bounds); x += imageSize.width ) {
            NSRect tileRect = NSMakeRect(x, y, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
            if ( NSIntersectsRect(tileRect, dirtyRect) ) {
                NSRect destRect = NSIntersectionRect(tileRect, dirtyRect);
                [image drawInRect:destRect
                         fromRect:NSOffsetRect(destRect, -x, -y)
                        operation:NSCompositeSourceOver 
                         fraction:1.0];
            }
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: What do I do with the TiledBackgroundView then? Is it a box that I put onto the window with IB or is this subclassing the whole window? In which case, how do I only have the background image fill part of the window?

Comment: You should make this the content view for the window. In interface builder, expand the disclosure triangle for the window. Directly under it will be a view that is the window's content view. In the class inspector, change that view's class from NSView to TiledBackgroundView.

Comment: Thanks, this answer along with this doc (which I found because after reading this answer I knew what to search for) helped me. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html

Answer (score 0):

No control automatically tiles a background for you.

Remember that `NSView`s (usually subclasses) do all the drawing - so, for instance, that gray area would be a subclass of `NSView` and you could put the images inside of it.

To actually draw the tiled image (by the `NSView` subclass), Madsen's method is usable, but not the most convenient. The easiest way is something along the lines of:

```
NSColor *patternColor = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"imageName"]];
[patternColor setFill];
NSRectFill(rectToDraw);
```

which you should put in the `-drawRect:` method of your custom view class. It creates an `NSColor` which represents a tiled image. Note that it can also be a subclass of a scroll/clip view, etc.

I am not too familiar with Core Animation but it is useful for manipulating views, and might be a direction you want to look at concerning the view drawing the image (and that view only).